# Applescript that responds to key presses?

Tags: applescript, bash

I want to write an AppleScript that

1. runs (in a loop) until I press <kbd>esc</kbd>
2. "listens" for keystrokes <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, etc.
3. executes a given command for a each keypress (running a shell command `ddcctl` to change secondary monitor brightness/contrast)

I've searched and everything I find relates to *simulating* a key press.

(If this can be done in `bash` that's fine but I don't know enough shell scripting to even start...)

---

**UPDATE**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297638/bash-how-to-end-infinite-loop-with-any-key-pressed) tip, I wrote the shell script below, which works great, but only if I run it *within Terminal.* Is there any way to run this script 'invisibly', say, from Spotlight or via AppleScript `do shell script`, and have it respond until I exit?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi
keypress=''
while [ "$k" != "^[" ]; do
    case "$k" in
        1) ddcctl -d 1 -b 10;;
        2) ddcctl -d 1 -b 20;;
        3) ddcctl -d 1 -b 30;;
        # ...etc...
        0) ddcctl -d 1 -b 100;;
    esac
    k="`cat -v`"
done
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
exit 0
```

Comment: You'll need a different way of capturing key-presses if you want to capture not only within your focused window but system wide. I would suggest that instead you bind the keys you want to use to each execute your apple script with a simple parameter (i.e. bind for example ctrl-1 to execute your script with the parameter 1).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of accomplishing this is probably to use Automator to create a Service. The service should just execute your a bash script similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ddcctl -d 1 -b 10
```

Then in System Preference under Keyboard, add a keyboard shortcut to activate your Service.

This way your shortcut will work across all programs.

You'll probably need to do this for each of the 10 keyboard shortcuts you need.

Comment: Yeah, I know many ways to run a single command from a keystroke; but this is not what I want. I want to launch something, then be able to adjust brightness via 1-9.

Comment: This can still be achieved using the same method. The bash script that is executed by the keyboard shortcut could just check if your "something" is launched - if it isn't, it doesn't do anything. Then create a dummy program that when launched just hangs around doing nothing until it is closed down.

Comment: Alternatively if you want to create a standalone program that does this is to use the addGlobalMonitorForEvents method in NSEvent in AppKit. However, I have no idea how easy that is to do from AppleScript. It is relatively easy to do so from Swift however.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found an amazing solution. You can change the brightness with `-b [+-]number`. For example:

`#!/bin/bash
ddcctl -d 1 -b +10`

Reference: [How to get system volume control on Dell monitor](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-get-system-volume-control-on-dell-monitor.1855929/#post-21480416) .

Comment: **Reread the OP. This does not in any way answer the question asked in the OP!**